# JavaFX pane.getChildren().remove(child) throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, observablelist

I'm trying to create a component which registers a listener on parent of a Line and when it changes it adds/removes a rectangle on Parent of line.

You can see the code bellow.
Basically I have 2 buttons

- Add > Adds the line to demoPane
- Remove > Removes the line from demoPane

I also register a listener on line parent as I already explained.

When I click on Add Button everything goes fine... The line is added and subsequently the rectangle is also added.

When i press remove the line is removed from demoPane but on removal of rectangle, it is thrown the following exception :

```
 -Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = AnchorPane[id=demoPane]
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(Unknown Source)
    at demo.Delete.lambda$2(Delete.java:63)
```

This happens on line 63 which is where I remove rectangle from demoPane

```
private static void mountDemo(AnchorPane demoPane) {
        Button buttonAdd = new Button("Add");
        Button buttonRemove = new Button("Remove");
        Line line = new Line(100, 100, 400, 100);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20);

        demoPane.getChildren().add(buttonAdd);
        demoPane.getChildren().add(buttonRemove);

        buttonAdd.setOnMouseClicked((event)->demoPane.getChildren().add(line));
        buttonRemove.setOnMouseClicked((event)->demoPane.getChildren().remove(line));

        line.parentProperty().addListener((observable, oldParent, newParent)->{
            if(newParent != null)
                ((Pane)newParent).getChildren().add(rectangle);
            else
                ((Pane)oldParent).getChildren().remove(rectangle);
        }); 
    }
```

Can anyone help me with it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from this code?

Comment: @James_D I think [this](http://pastebin.com/yY27EutA) is the simplest example possible.
Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: While debugging your code I noticed that in the moment in which you're removing the rectangle, the line has no parent but root still has line as a child :SSS  Anyway, I don't quite understand why are you trying to do this. If every time you add or remove the line you want to do the same with the rectangle, why don't you do it in the same buttonAdd & buttonRemove setOnMouseClicked events? I mean, what exactly do you win doing it this way?

Comment: @SuicidePlatypus thanks for the answer.
The square without any particular position it was just to simplify the problem.

Actually I'm trying to create an arrow, by placing a triangle at the end of the line and I want to not worry about the arrow. This component would monitor endX and endY from line  and place the triangle via listener on this properties. When the line is removed from the Parent I also have to remove the triangle, that's why I register a listener on parent of line to remove or add the triangle. 

I just wanted to work with this arrow as a single Node

Comment: I think this is technically a bug, but as @SuicidePlatypus points out it's a very strange way of accomplishing this functionality. You could use a `Path`, or just put the two things in a `Group` and add/remove the `Group` from the `Pane`.

Comment: @James_D _I think this is technically a bug_ hmm .. I agree as far as the error message is concerned, but not so sure about the real issue: we do have the node's parentProperty and the parent's children state as two observables - which state (of the other) do we expect when observing any? Isn't this a subtle variant of the dilemma with not completely orthogonal properties? And what are the choices for core implementation: as-is the parent is updated before the list, the other way round (first add/remove then update the parent) would pose a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know what you're trying to do I would suggest creating a new class. Assuming you want an **horizontal** arrow between two points:

```
public class Arrow extends Path {
    private static Double ARROW_HEAD_SIZE = 10D;
    private Point2D startPoint;
    private Point2D endPoint;

    public Arrow(Point2D start, Point2D end) {
        super();
        setStrokeWidth(1);
        startPoint = start;
        endPoint = end;
        draw();
    }

    public void draw() {
        getElements().clear();
        // Goto start point
        MoveTo startMove = new MoveTo();
        startMove.setX(startPoint.getX());
        startMove.setY(startPoint.getY());
        getElements().add(startMove);
        // Horizontal line from start point to end point
        HLineTo line = new HLineTo();
        line.setX(endPoint.getX());
        getElements().add(line);
        // First line for the arrow
        LineTo firstArrow = new LineTo();
        firstArrow.setX(endPoint.getX() - ARROW_HEAD_SIZE);
        firstArrow.setY(endPoint.getY() - ARROW_HEAD_SIZE);
        getElements().add(firstArrow);
        // Return to end point
        MoveTo lastMove = new MoveTo();
        lastMove.setX(endPoint.getX());
        lastMove.setY(endPoint.getY());
        getElements().add(lastMove);
        // Second line for the arrow
        LineTo secondArrow = new LineTo();
        secondArrow.setY(endPoint.getY() + ARROW_HEAD_SIZE);
        secondArrow.setX(endPoint.getX() - ARROW_HEAD_SIZE);
        getElements().add(secondArrow);
    }
}
```

That way, from your main you only need to add/remove an instance from that class:

```
Point2D startPoint = new Point2D(50, 50);
Point2D endPoint = new Point2D(100, 50);
Arrow arrow = new Arrow(startPoint, endPoint);
buttonAdd.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> root.getChildren().add(arrow));
buttonRemove.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> root.getChildren().remove(arrow));
```

Also, instead of using a Path you could make your new class extend some kind of Pane and just join inside of it a couple lines, or a line and an triangle or whatever.

Comment: Ok I will invest on your solution
Thanks @SuicidePlatypus